# Two commutator relations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, lie-algebras

$\newcommand{\ad}{\operatorname{ad}}$Let $R$ be an associative ring. Set $[x, y] = xy - yx$ and $\ad_x(-) = [x, -]: R \to R$.

1. Is there a formula for $(ab)^n$ in general? I found one formula for the group theoretic commutator, i.e.,
   $$
   (xy)^n = x^{\binom{n}1} y^{\binom{n}1} [y,x]^{\binom{n}{2}}[[y,x],x]^{\binom{n}{3}} \cdots [\cdots[[[ y, x],x],x]\cdots,x]^{\binom{n}{n}},
   $$
   I am wondering if there is any nice formula for the ring theoretic commutator.
   BTW, I found https://mathoverflow.net/q/78813/19222, which is a for $(x+y)^n$.
2. In characteristic $p$, suppose that $r$ commutes with $[x, r]$, we should have $\ad_{rx}^{p-1}(r) = -r\ad_x^{p-1}(r^{p-1})$. But now I have no idea how to prove it.

Any hints? Thank you!

Comment: I suspect the answer to question 1 is negative. Hall's formula for groups relies on the fact that the elements are invertible, which allows the right hand side to have huge exponents compared to the left. But in a ring, with $a$ and $b$ not being invertible, you are limited to degree $2n$ -- any higher degree cannot be "balanced out".

Comment: What kind of formula are you even looking for in 1? What would it be for $n=2$? -- For no. 2,  writing out both sides with the commutator for $p=2,3$ should give an idea what's going on.